The functor that preserves the direct sum is an additive functor
I am learning about additive categories on the Stacks Project, and I encountered some difficulties in proving that functor that preserves direct sums is an additive functor. 
There is such a description in the proof:

Let $f, g$ be maps. Then $f + g$ is equal to the composition
$$A \rightarrow A \oplus A \xrightarrow{diag(f, g)} B \oplus B \rightarrow B$$

My first question is, what is $i: A \rightarrow A \oplus A$ and $p: B \oplus B \rightarrow B$? Since we have $(A \oplus A, i^{A}_{1}, i^{A}_{2}, p^{A}_{1}, p^{A}_{2})$ and $(B \oplus B, i^{B}_{1}, i^{B}_{2}, p^{B}_{1}, p^{B}_{2})$, is $i = i^{A}_{1} + i^{A}_{2}$, $p = p^{B}_{1} + p^{B}_{2}$?
My second question is, how to prove that the following commutative diagram holds?
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
F(A) & \xrightarrow{\alpha} & F(A \oplus A) \\
 & \searrow{\beta} & \uparrow{\psi} \\
& & F(A) \oplus F(A) \\
\end{array}$$
I cannot understand the proof in the original text:

For the triangle on the left, we use that $F(A \oplus A) \rightarrow F(A) \oplus F(A)$ is an isomorphism to see that it suffice to check after composition with this map and this check is trivial.

Attempt for the second question: If indeed $i = i^{A}_{1} + i^{A}_{2}$ holds, then similarly, there is $\beta = \tilde{i_{1}^{A}} + \tilde{i_{2}^{A}}$ where $(F(A) \oplus F(A), \tilde{i_{1}^{A}}, \tilde{i_{2}^{A}}, \tilde{p_{1}^{A}}, \tilde{p_{2}^{A}})$ is direct sum of $F(A)$ and $F(A)$. Since universal property, we have $F(i_{j}^{A}) = \psi \circ \tilde{i_{j}^{A}}$ where $j \in \{1, 2\}$. So commutative diagram means $\psi \circ \beta = \psi \circ (\tilde{i_{1}^{A}} + \tilde{i_{2}^{A}}) = F(i^{A}_{1}) + F(i^{A}_{2}) \stackrel{?}{=} F(i^{A}_{1} + i^{A}_{2}) = \alpha$. But I cannot prove the question mark step.

$i=i_1+i_2,p=p_1+p_2$ is correct. Really, the map $A\to A\oplus A\cong A\times A$ is the standard diagonal map $\Delta_A$ (defined as having projections equal to identity on either factor) and $A\oplus A\cong A\sqcup A\to A$ is the standard codiagonal map $\nabla_A$ (in more conventional notation; $\Delta_A=i,\nabla_A=p$ all the same).
As for your second question, I think the phrasing by the Stacks project isn't great. Neither $F(A)$ nor $F(A\oplus A)$ have a universal property (a priori), so in abstraction it is not easy to check $\alpha=\psi\beta$. However, since $F(A)\oplus F(A)$ does have a universal property, we can instead check $\psi^{-1}\alpha=\beta$. What is $\psi^{-1}$? Well, there is a canonical map $\phi:F(A\oplus A)\cong F(A\times A)\to F(A)\times F(A)\cong F(A)\oplus F(A)$ (in general, a canonical map $F(\varprojlim)\to\varprojlim F$) defined via $p_k\phi=F(p_k)$. $\psi$ arises similarly from viewing $A\sqcup A\cong A\oplus A$ and using the coproduct universal property. And, again using the universal properties and basic biproduct facts, you can check that $\phi\circ\psi=\mathrm{Id}_{F(A)\oplus F(A)}$ always, regardless of $F$. In other words, $F(A)\oplus F(A)$ is canonically a retract of $F(A\oplus A)$, $F$ any functor. When $F$ preserves direct sums, then necessarily $\phi=\psi^{-1}$ follows.
Ok, so check $\phi\alpha=\beta$ instead, $F(A)\to F(A)\oplus F(A)$. Use universal properties! Be categorical first, and Abelian later, would be my advice.
$p_k\phi\alpha=F(p_k)\alpha=F(p_k\circ\Delta_A)=F(\mathrm{Id}_A)=\mathrm{Id}_{F(A)}$ for $k=1,2$ so $\phi\alpha=\beta=\Delta_{F(A)}$ indeed holds. The exact same proof shows that $F(A\oplus A)\overset{F(p)}{\to}F(A)$ equals $F(A\oplus A)\cong F(A)\oplus F(A)\overset{p}{\to}F(A)$.
